# Cordova App CSS being overridden on iOS Simulator

Tags: android, ios, css, cordova, mobile

I have just transferred over my cordova project from my windows machine to a Mac to port it to a iOS. So far I have just developed the android version of my app.

I come to launch my app on the iOS simulator and some of the CSS is either not working or being overridden.

**CSS**

```
div.loginBox input[type="password"], div.loginBox input[type="email"], div.loginBox input[type="text"] {
    font-size: 16pt;
    width: 85%;
    height: 60px;
    background: #41a4bb;
    border: 2px solid #41a4bb;
    font-family: "Segoe UI Light", "Calibri Light", "Segoe UI", "Calibri", Arial;
    display:inline-block;
    outline: none;
    margin: 2px;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
}
```

An example above is a text box for both email and password. On the android version there is no border-radius for the input fields but they seem to have it on the iOS versions.

Comment: Hi, I know it's been so late. But did you manage this issue? I'm currently facing same. Can you help me with it?